# Prove Closed Set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

From Stephen Abbott Understanding Analysis book, exercise 3.2.2 there is a set $A$ :
$$A=\left\{(-1)^n + \frac{2}{n}:n=1,2,3,...\right\}$$
I know that this is not an open set because no neighborhood is contained
in $A$, but then how do I properly prove that $A$ is a closed set based on the definition in the book : "A set $F\subseteq\Bbb R$ is closed if it contains its limit points"?

Comment: It is not closed either, because it does not contain the limit point $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to prove this from your definition is to first identify the limit points and then to verify that $A$ contains them.

First, note that $(-1)^n + \frac{2}{n}$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, \dots$ splits into two convergent subseries:

$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} (-1)^{2k} + \frac{2}{2k} = 1
$$

and

$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} (-1)^{2k+1} + \frac{2}{2k+1} = -1.
$$

Therefore, it has exactly two limit points: $-1$ and $1$.

Finally, $1 \in A$, but $-1 \notin A$, so $A$ does not contain all of its limit points. Therefore, $A$ is not closed.